# Web Crawler issue in perl

Tags: perl, web-crawler, libwww-perl

I had built a web crawler in Perl.

I am using

```
HTML::ContentExtractor

LWP::UserAgent 

HTML::LinkExtor
```

to extract text form webpages.

Reference link for sample code [web cralwer perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157269/perl-print-matched-content-only)

**Issue:**

The issue is that it does not get text from web pages that have the extension as `.aspx` .
It works perfectly for other webpages.I could not figure out the issue why this crawler fails for `aspx` pages.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript on the pages?

Comment: Yes those web pages have Javascript.

Comment: javascript is not supported. you have to create POST or get requests

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do that?I had tried $ua->post( $url, \%form ) $ua->post( $url, \@form ) but of no use.@run

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access a process a website with JavaScript, use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)